# How to create list of Maps from List of Object in java without having getKey method?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

How to create a list of maps, where each key name is inferred from name of the class attribute, and value is to be put by getter method

I am having following class in java

```
class DTA {
  private String id;
  private String age;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "DTA{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", age='" + age + '\'' +
            '}';
  }

  public DTA(String id, String age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

I am having a list of objects of type DTA

```
List<DTA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(new DTA("A", "15"));
listA.add(new DTA("B", "25"));
```

I want to create an ordered list of maps (somewhat like scala) which has following content.

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>>

List(Map("id"->"A", "age"->"15"), Map("id"->"B", "age"->"25"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without "dynamics", the straight forward thing might look like:

```
List<Map<String, String>> x = listA
            .stream()
            .map(this::toMap)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with a local helper, such as:

```
private Map<String, String> toMap(DTA dta) {
    Map<String, String> rv = new HashMap<>();
    rv.put("id", dta.getId());
    rv.put("age", dta.getAge());
    return rv;
}
```

In order to be fully dynamic here, you would have to use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to query the field names. You can find examples how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778288/java-refelection-find-fields-name-and-value).

But I strongly suggest to **not** do that: reflection should always be your last resort. The notion of *DTA* suggests that you have that object data coming from some "service" anyway. If so, why first serialize into a specific DTA class, to then "flatten" that information into some generic Map structure?!

Meaning: when that service gives you objects that are serialized as, say JSON, or XML ... then it would be much better to simply use a library like gson or jackson to **directly** deserialize that data into such generic "flat" Map-based objects. Jackson for example has a [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) class. When you deserialize into such objects, you get that mapping of field names for free! See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) more example code.

The point is: identifying fields using reflection is possible. But *reflection* code is always tedious, and error prone. If possible, stay away from doing that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the tool used to "look into" the contents of classes in Java is called *reflection*. For example, if your object is a POJO (Plain Old Java Object), you can iterate over all fields in the class in the following way:

```
DTA obj; // some object, I assume it's initialized
Field[] fields = DTA.class.getDeclaredFields();
Map<String, Object> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
for (field : fields) {
    boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible(); // check if class has access control disabled
    field.setAccessible(true); // disable access control (private/protected) to extract value    
    valuesMap.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
    field.setAccessible(wasAccessible); // return flag to initial value   
}
```

However, accessing values via reflection this way is notoriously hacky. Unless you have good reasons to do it yourself, try using a framework that automates tasks like that rather than writing code like this from scratch.

Also, reflection is *slow*. Accessing `Field` entities like that for every single object is suboptimal, if you ever want to really write code like this, you should cache the `Field` objects in a `Map<String, Field>` and only do the `setAccessible` override and the `Field` retrieval once for every collection of `DTA` objects.

Comment: A nice list of reasons why you should not use reflection, but together with an example how to do it. Good answer, worth an upvote!